# What is the purpose of closing a database connection

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I was just doing a lesson in CodeCademy under the 'Intermediate PHP' course for the lesson called 'Connecting to the Database'. In the last step, the task is to terminate the database connection. I might be asking this question a little too early on, but since I'm new to this, what is the purpose of terminating a database connection?

[image]

Comment: You really don't need to. Ending a PHP script will close out all of the connections it created

Comment: This is just bad or outdated advice. In production code you should be using a connection pool. You don't close the connection you return it to the pool. In many cases this is done automatically.

Comment: This is an /outdated/ suggestion mainly because a database connection is a limited resource (although the limit is pretty high depending on the rdbms). The RDBMs usually have a limit of how many connections can be open at the same time.

Comment: It's an advise for scripts that does a db manipulation in the middle and keep running for a long time (of course, ending the script should release the attached connexions.) If one is using a pool, no need to worry about it because the connexion will be reused when needed by some other process …otherwise you're holding a connexion which isn't an infinite ressource.